# How to Isolate Javascript on 3rd Party Sites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

We've building a small self-rendering Javascript component that will be embedded on many third party sites.  Our Javascript will depend on several common libraries (zepto, hogan, etc).

What's the best way to isolate our Javascript from polluting the global namespace or interfering with other Javascript on a third party site?  Are there special error handling considerations/wrappers we should use to ensure our Javascript doesn't prevent rendering?

The goal is to have a single script embedded on the third party site that renders interactive content in the DOM, but otherwise remains entirely isolated.

Comment: Best way to avoid polluting the global namespace is not to use the global namespace. The second-best way it to stick all your global variables inside an object that is very very unlikely to be named by anybody else.

Comment: why is this closed damn it

Comment: How is this "too broad"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more about this, I'm going to use a closure based wrapper and jQuery with noConflict mode like so:

```
(function(window, document, undefined){
  // Inject contents of jquery-2.0.3.min.js here
  var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true); //Remove global jQuery and alias locally

  //Define all application classes and init here using local $
})(window, document);
```